# Get the number of pages a table spans

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I work with several ODT documents which include tables to be printed and filled in by hand. These tables contain in the header a cell with text "`Sheet ____ of ____`" to be filled in by hand once printed. I'd like to automate these fields, if possible.

Is possible to get the number of pages a table spans and/or to get the n-th-spanned-page for a table, in order to include it in the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t have access to LibreOffice; this answer seems to work for Microsoft Word 2007.

First of all, I suggest that you insert section breaks between the tables and restart page numbering, so you can get “Sheet 1 of ___” on the first page of each table. 
(But you probably already know that, right?)

Next, insert a bookmark at the end of each table, just before the section break. 
Give them meaningful names like “end_of_table_1”. 
Then, in the header for each section, after the “Sheet 1 of ”, insert a PageRef field
that references the bookmark at the end of that section.

Comment: Starting a section for each table and using the bookmark trick works very nicely, thanks. Unfortunately that breaks the overall document numbering in the footer (which is itself reset for the Appendix that contains all of the tables). I think I'll try marking the start page of the table and the end page of the table and see if it can be calculated with a macro.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Libreoffice Help website:

> Choose Insert - Fields - Page Number to insert a page number at the current cursor position.
>           If you see the text "Page number" instead of the number, choose View - Field names.
>
> However, these fields will change position when you add or remove text. So it is best to insert the page number field into a header or footer that has the same position and that is repeated on every page.
>
> Choose Insert - Header - (name of page style) or Insert - Footer - (name of page style) to add a header or footer to all pages with the current page style.

[Link with source](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Page_Numbers)

Comment: This inserts a document's or section's page number, rather than the table's page number. E.g., if the table is on page 5 and ends on page 8, the _table's_ header should say `Sheet 1 of 4` on page 5, `Sheet 2 of 4` on page 6 and so on.